# ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone - bigint . - ( a.DURATION

Tags: postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

```
SELECT  
    a.CARRIER,
    b. CARRIER 
FROM 
    V_CARRIER_NOT_MATCH a, V_HGC_NOT_MATCH b
WHERE
    a.END_DATE_TIME >= b.END_DATE_TIME
                       - (a.DURATION
                       + (SELECT DISTINCT TIME_ADJ_MINS * 60
                            FROM TYPE_PARAM
                           WHERE CARRIER = a.CARRIER))
                    / 24
                    / 60
                    / 60;
```

Comment: kindly rectify the issue.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You need to convert your `bigint` to an `interval`, `make_interval()` is a good way to do that.

Comment: Trying to implement interval but still getting error .Can change the piece of code and paste below.

Comment: will some one format the piece of code.